# What is the purpose of hG in the unix command `ls -lahG`?

Tags: unix

I've seen `ls -lahG` reference in a few tutorials when `ls -la` seems to work just as well.  I googled `-lahG` but I can't find any explanation.

Comment: Not a bash command: `ls` is provided by your operating system, not by bash. Thus, bash has zero control over what those flags mean.

Comment: use your man.  `man ls`.  Googling it didn't help because the whole string means nothing, it's each individual flag that means something specific, and Google isn't smart enough to determine that that's what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Per [ExplainShell](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ls+-lahG):

- `-h` provides human-readable output
- `-G` avoids printing group names

Comment: Cool!  I've never seen this website before.  This should be very helpful.  Thanks